# How to check if Bluetooth headphones connected before asking permission

Tags: android, bluetooth

It's now required to check `BLUETOOTH_CONNECT` permission in runtime when targeting Android 12 or higher (see [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions)).

My app using Bluetooth only to connect to currently connected headphones (to redirect an audio to Bluetooth headphones during WebRTC conference call). So, I don't need to request the permission if a user do not use any Bluetooth headphones.

**I know how to request permission, but** the problem is that to check if the headphones connected, I first need to request the permission.
But I don't want to request permission if no headphones connected.

As I understand, if I ask for permission as recommended, then all users would be asked to grand the permission even if they don't use Bluetooth headphones in my game. This is an unnecessary permission to ask a user and they won't thanks us for it.

But without checking for permission first, checking the status of headphones (connected or not) becomes impossible. How to resolve the catch 22?

This is my code to check if Bluetooth headphones connected:

```
private static boolean isBluetoothHeadsetConnected() {
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    return mBluetoothAdapter != null && mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()
        && mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileConnectionState(BluetoothHeadset.HEADSET) == BluetoothHeadset.STATE_CONNECTED;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have the user do something the first time to positively indicate that they want you to do something regarding Bluetooth headphones. That could be clicking a button or on an item in a settings screen. At that point, you can explain how this works (you need permission, and in the future you will try to auto-connect to the headphones), then request the permission, then try working with the headphones.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) class to check the current audio outputs of the device.

You can call the [getDevices()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#getDevices(int)) method and receive an array of [AudioDeviceInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioDeviceInfo) objects.

In that `AudioDeviceInfo` you'll have all the information about the connected devices.

Comment: A great answer. Now instead of the method I can use the one-liner: `isBluetoothConnected = Arrays.stream(audioManager.getDevices(GET_DEVICES_OUTPUTS)).anyMatch(info -> info.getType() == TYPE_BLUETOOTH_SCO || info.getType() == TYPE_BLUETOOTH_A2DP);` And no permission required at all.